# WPF Application doesn't show up on other machines

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I made a WPF Application and I can run it without trouble. But when I send the Release Build to my Friend it just won't open up, but the Process runs in the background.

I assume that the reason is, that he doesn't have .NET installed on his machine.

My question is when I want to publish my Application, should I use an installer, which checks, if .NET is installed and when necessary instlles .NET, or is my friends PC just weird? I think that I read, that Windows 10 automatically installs .NET, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: .NET should be included by default with Windows 10. I suspect some other error is happening; check the Event Viewer on your friend's machine, and select "Windows Log" -> "Application". If there's some specific error, please update your question with the error message, because otherwise this question isn't really answerable.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that windows had an Event Viewer. I found out, that the crash was due to a corrupted dll. (KERNELBASE.dll).